# Button overlayed on a GridView does not respond to OnClick events

Tags: android, animation, button, gridview, alpha

I have a screen in my app which displays some categories for the users to select, in a GridView, as following:

[image]

When a user clicks on a category, a button appears for the user to continue, as following:

[image]

The problem is, that the green button that appeared does not respond to @OnClick (I am using ButterKnife for views).

Here is the Layout xml:

**activity_select_categories.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/g"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/h"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:text="CATEGORIES" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridView_selectCategoriesLayout_categories"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="2dp"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="2dp"
            />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/button_selectCategoriesLayout_continue"
    android:alpha="0.8">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#22c064"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#22c064"
        android:src="@drawable/checkmark"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the custom grid view element:

**grid_tem.xml**

```
<com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/root"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">

<com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridItem_squareImageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />

<com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridItem_selectedColor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#e85349"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:alpha="0.45"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<com.entu.artapp.utils.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/gridItem_constantGrey"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:alpha="0.45"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

<com.entu.artapp.utils.RectangularLinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/s"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridItem_selectedCheckMark"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/checkmark"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        />

</com.entu.artapp.utils.RectangularLinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/gridItem_progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridItem_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textAllCaps="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

And here is how I set the OnClick for my button:

```
@OnClick(R.id.button_selectCategoriesLayout_continue)
public void setContinueButton () {
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("followedCategories", categoriesSelectedList);
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("followedCategoriesNames", categoriesNamesSelectedList);
    ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();
}
```

Can anyone help me in solving why does the button not respond to OnClick? 
ButterKnife.inject(this) has been called.

Extra: I have an alpha animation on the button. Although I am calling .setVisibility(VIEW.GONE), the button disappears, but the place where the button is/was cannot be clicked. I have read on similar topics on animations and VIEW.GONE conflicts that it might be a bug, and suggested using .clearAnimation(). But, if i call that, the alpha animation resets, and it messes up my UI.

Can anyone help me solve any of these problems?

Cheers!

**EDIT #1:** The code where i animated the button:

```
@InjectView(R.id.button_selectCategoriesLayout_continue)
RelativeLayout continueButton;

categoriesGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

[...]

if (categoriesNamesSelectedList.size() == 0) {
                        deselectedAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            continueButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });
                    continueButton.startAnimation(deselectedAnimation);
                }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you animate the button's appearance and disappearance? (Keep in mind that in your code it's not the button that's clickable, but the button's parent, the `RelativeLayout`)

Comment: Yes, i know, the listener is on the layout. But it still does not work.

Comment: Show us the code where you animate the button.

Comment: The extra code has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button inside the RelativeLayout steals the click event from the layout. You should delete the Button from the RelativeLayout (as you anyway don't use it) and set the background of the RelativeLayout instead of the button.

Comment: Thanks alot mate! it worked. May there be more helpful people like you.